# Using Logback to catalina.out

Tags: java, tomcat, logback, tomcat9

I am using Logback in an application running in Tomcat. While my application works and, in the debugger, I see my logging statements reached, these statements never reach */opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out*. (By the way, I do see these statements in the IntelliJ IDEA debugger console, but upon deployment, they don't reach *catalina.out*.) Where do I begin?

In my WAR, *WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml* looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.out</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
      <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{40} %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

In code, I do this for example:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Validator
{
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( Validator.class );
  ...

  public void foo()
  {
    logger.info( "Called foo()" );
```

Correspondingly, in *pom.xml* dependencies, I have this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>${logback-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
  <version>${logback-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I also tried this in *logback.xml*. It didn't create the file. All logfiles are owned by `tomcat:tomcat`. Tomcat owns the thread that writes to the log.

```
<file>${catalina.base}/logs/test.log</file>
```

Comment: May be tomcat `owns` that file. Try using another one. Messages should appear there with a Console appender I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the *slf4j* JARs and multiple bindings. See

https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings.

I eliminated *slf4j-simple* from my dependencies as shown above. The fact that two *slf4j* JARs were in conflict barred in essence *logback.xml* from having any effect upon logging behavior. Upon fixing this, JUnit tests still worked, the IDE-embedded Tomcat began to reveal `TRACE`-level statements when the level was set to `TRACE`, ditto when deployed to a real Tomcat installation where the statements come out (in *catalina.out* in my case).

One additional observation I can make is that if a log-level configuration change is made (say, by hand directly on *logback.xml* on the path */opt/tomcat/webapps/application/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml*), I found that Tomcat had to be bounced for it to take effect (even though I played with `<configuration scan="true">`, etc.).